# VB6: Get hWnd of a child control inside a 3rd Party control

Tags: vb6, user32, hwnd

I have a vb6 third party UpDown Control (let it be ControlX), with UISpy i could see that ControlX has 2 controls inside, one is a "ThunderRT6TextBox" the other is a "UpDown20WndClass".

I am drawing a border around ControlX. I am using the ControlX hWnd, and i draw the border like this:

```
   hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, tPS)

   GetClientRect hwnd, controlXRect

   DrawEdge hdc, controlXRect, BDR_SUNKENOUTER, BF_RECT
```

The problem is that the border is drawn around the ThunderRT6TextBox but not the UpDown20WndClass (maybe the ControlX hWnd returns it's inner ThunderRT6TextBox control hwnd).

I would like to get the ControlX's inner UpDown20WndClass control hWnd, to draw a border around it.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hopefully the wrapped control having UpDown20WndClass isn't part of the Microsoft Forms 2.0 library.  This library has caveats against its use in VB6 programs and cannot legally be redistributed, effectively making it useless for most programs.

Answer (score 0):

If the updown control has been made a child of the textbox, you should be able to use EnumChildWindows to find it. You might use WinSpy to see if there's an overall parent hwnd that contains both the textbox and the updown, then enum for it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately there is no overall parent.

Answer (score 0):

I when get ControlX hwnd it returns the hwnd of the "ThunderRT6TextBox". To get the "UpDown20WndClass" hwnd, i need its parent hwnd (ControlX hwnd).  I used GetParent with "ThunderRT6TextBox" hwnd, and got the common parent hwnd, and then with FindWindowEx i got the "UpDown20WndClass".